# c#: How to create generic class with type parameter to be either string or integer?

Tags: c#

I want to create a generic class with 1 type parameter. And I want to restrict that type parameter is either a string or a number with no decimal points.

How can I do that? I have tried

```
public class BaseClass<T> 
{
}
```

But how can I restrict T? I tried `where T : string` but I get an error message:

> 'string' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter

Comment: Frame challenge: what operation are you planning on performing inside this class? i.e. what method are you planning on using that both `string` and `int` implement?

Comment: "a non-sealed class" and "public **sealed** class String"

Answer (score 5):

> And I want to restrict that type parameter is either a string or a number with no decimal points.

C# doesn't support that. There are a few constraints, e.g.

- Must be a reference type
- Must be a value type
- Must be derived from class C (or that class itself) or an implementation of interface I (or that interface itself) - but the class C has to be non-sealed
- Must have a public parameterless constructor

(There are more recently-introduced ones too, around unmanaged types and also nullability.)

But none of those fit with "only string or integer types". You could check that at execution time, but that really defeats a significant chunk of the point of generics.

Comment: What a precise and comprehensive answer! But it doesn't propose any relevant solution.

Comment: @rotabor: The question didn't provide enough information about the bigger picture of what the OP was actually trying to achieve - instead it was "Is there a way for this proposed solution to work" and the answer is simply "no". If the question had provided more context in terms of the purpose, I could have proposed a solution to that.

Comment: Agree - details are missing. And it could be the XY problem, as usually, when the author resolved his main problem in the way which produces another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Joe's question is still hot, of cause.

But if you somehow need what you ask, you can implement this trick:

```
interface IFromInt {
    int Avalue { get; set; }
    // ... other members to work with ints
}
interface IFromString {
    string Avalue { get; set; }
    // ... other members to work with strings
}
class Aclass : IFromInt, IFromString {
    object avalue;
    public Aclass(int i) {
        avalue = i;
    }
    public Aclass(string s) {
        avalue = s;
    }
    int IFromInt.Avalue { get => (int)avalue; set { avalue = value; } }
    string IFromString.Avalue { get => (string)avalue; set { avalue = value; } }
    // ... other members implementation
}
static class Programm {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var a = new Aclass(13); // class-typed variable can be initialized both with int or string
        var d = new Aclass(1.3); // error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'int'
        IFromInt i = a; // int operations are accessible through interface-typed variable only
        Console.WriteLine(i.Avalue); // 13
        IFromString s = a; // string operations are accessible through interface-typed variable only
        s.Avalue = "thirteen";
        Console.WriteLine(s.Avalue); // thirteen
        s.Avalue = 1.1; // error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'
        a.Avalue = 6; // error CS1061 'Aclass' doesn't contain a definition for 'Avalue' ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put such a restriction in a constraint, but at least you can restrict the usage to string and int so that it throws at runtime, if types other than int and string are used as T.

```
using System;

public class BaseClass<T> 
{
    static BaseClass()
    {
        if (typeof(T) is var t && t != typeof(int) && t != typeof(string)) 
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("'BaseClass<T>': type parameter T"
               + $" is restricted to string and int, {t} is not supported.");
        }
    }
}   
...
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = new BaseClass<int>();
        var y = new BaseClass<string>();
        var z = new BaseClass<long>(); // throws
    }
```